# Java: конкатенация строк и Integer.getInteger

Tags: строки, java

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой парснига int, объясните, пожалуйста, как думает компилятор в этот момент и почему он не хочет выдавать мне правильное значение.

```
String s = "task_123";
String[] paths = s.split("_");
int type = 1;
int i = Integer.getInteger(Integer.toString(type) + paths[1], 0);
int j = Integer.getInteger(type + paths[1], 0);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(j);
```

Выводится 0, 0, а должен 1123, 1123

Как так?

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/qDxfuf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Компилятор здесь не при чем. Вы используете не тот метод (см. javadoc [Integer.getInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29)). Вы пытаетесь получить значение типа `Integer`, которое соответствует имени системного свойства. Т.к. это свойство не определено, то возвращается значение по умолчанию 0, которое вы сами и указали в вызове метода `getIneteger`.

Замените вызов `getInteger` на `parseInt`.

Comment: @a_gura - всё понял, невнимательность... Спасибо!